# inserting node in the beginning of linked list using codeblocks

Tags: c++

when i am inserting node in the beginning of the linked list, node is inserted in the beginning and is displayed. if i call display separately then it does not work and for inserting node at specific loc and at the end, calling display function works well.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node* create(int n)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    node* head = NULL;
    node* p;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        cout << "enter the data for node number " << i << endl;
        cin >> temp->data;
        temp->next = NULL;
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = temp;
        }
        else {
            p = head;
            while (p->next != NULL) {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = temp;
        }
    }
    return head;
}

node* insertatbeg(node* head)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    cout << "\nenter the data for first node" << endl;
    cin >> temp->data;
    temp->next = head;
    head = temp;
    return head;
}

void display(node* head)
{
    node* t = NULL;
    t = head;
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout << t->data << "->";
        t = t->next;
    }
}

node* insertatspecloc(node* head)
{
    int n;
    node* temp = NULL;
    node* t = head;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    cout << "enter the data of node after which you want to insert the 
            node "<<endl;
            cin
        >> n;
    cout << "\nenter the data for last node" << endl;
    cin >> temp->data;
    while (t->data != n) {
        t = t->next;
    }
    temp->next = t->next;
    t->next = temp;
    return head;
}

node* insertatend(node* head)
{
    node* temp = NULL;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    cout << "\nenter the data for last node" << endl;
    cin >> temp->data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    node* q;
    q = head;
    while (q->next != NULL) {
        q = q->next;
    }
    q->next = temp;
    return head;
}

int main()
{
    int n, a;
    struct node* head = NULL;
    cout << "enter the number of nodes u want to add";
    cin >> n;
    head = create(n);
    display(head);
    cout << "\npress 1 to add node at the beginning";
    cout << "\npress 2 to add node at the specific location";
    cout << "\npress 3 to add node at the end\n";
    cin >> a;
    if (a == 1) {
        insertatbeg(head);
        cout << "\nlinked list after insertion:\n";
        display(head);
    }
    if (a == 2) {
        insertatspecloc(head);
        cout << "\nlinked list after insertion:\n";
        display(head);
    }

    if (a == 3) {
        insertatend(head);
        cout << "\nLinked list after insertion:\n";
        display(head);
    }
}
```

Comment: this is not C++, this is "C printing to cout"

Comment: Advice -- before writing any code dealing with menus and prompts, you could have easily tested the workings of your linked list by directly calling the function(s) to insert.  This way your question is not inundated with unimportant things such as menus and prompts, and in addition it makes it easier for *you* to unit test your code.  If you don't do things this way, you wind up with a mountain of code and not know where to start figuring out what's wrong.  Ex: `int main() { head(create(5)); insertatbeg(head); insertatbeg(head); }` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling `insertatbeg(head);` the copy of `head` pointer is passed as the argument of your function, then in function you are modyfing local variable (copy of *head*)

```
 node *insertatbeg(node *head)
{
   node *temp=NULL;
   temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
   cout<<"\nenter the data for first node"<<endl;
   cin>>temp->data;
   temp->next=head;
   head=temp; // assign to local variable <---
   return head;
        }
```

and for this reason after executing *insertatbeg* `head` is not updated. `insertatbeg` returns pointer so you can resolve your issue by calling

```
head = insertatbeg(head);
```

or you can call function in above line without assigning but then you should pass `head` by reference to be able to modify original passed object in function:

```
 node *insertatbeg(node *& head) // pass pointer by reference
{
   node *temp=NULL;
   //...
   head = temp; // now it works
```

Comment: your suggestion is ok and code is working but other function such as insertion at specific loc and at the end is working without this(head = insertatbeg(head);) , why this happens ?

Comment: In these functions you dont modify 'head',  it is used to iterate through other elements to locate the position where you want to put new item.